# 99 Bottle song code in pure js

Tags: javascript

Can some please help me to tell me where i am going wrong in my code. I have been working on it for a little while but i am still stuck please help. this is my code so far. Thanks for the help in advance.

This is my javascript

```
var bottles; 
var beerNum = 99;

// This program will count to 99 for us

// Set up a counter variable, and start it on zero (good place to start)
var counter = 0;

// While loop
while (counter < 99) {

    // This line increments (or adds 1) to our counter each time the loop goes around.
    counter--;

    // This line finds the HTML element with an ID of "output" and puts the value of our counter in it, followed by a line break <br />
    // The += operator takes what's already stored and appends our new value to it
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += counter + "<br />";

}
if (bottles = beerNum){ 
    document.getElementById('output')>innerHTML += bottles + beerNum + "of beer on the wall";
}
```

And this is my HTML.

```
<p id="output"></p>
```

and i have a fiddle to accompany it

http://jsfiddle.net/Matt1990/X4UHD/39/

Comment: it should be document.getElementById('output').innerHTML

Comment: == is testing for equality, = is assignment. Also put test inside loop

Comment: What is the variable bottles used for?

Comment: Also, should it not be `counter++`?

Comment: So you start the counter at zero, decrement it each time through the loop and continue to loop as long as it's under 99. Any reason to write an infinite loop?

Comment: Start counter at 99 and test counter > 0 and remove the test for beernum

Comment: `document.getElementById('output')>innerHTML` you mean .innerHTML?

Comment: that is why i asked for help i need to start the song at 99 and go down to 1 bottle left and then i need it to out put my text and i don"t know how to output my text in the code.

Comment: Why do you need the `counter` variable at all? Just count down using `beerNum`.

Comment: You got plenty of tips here. Give it a go one more time. Else somebody can help u with code. U can do it :)

Comment: how do i count down using the beernum

Comment: `var beerNum=99;` ...... `beerNum--;`

Comment: When you have figured it out, have a look at the complete song. Note that the fiddle is no longer using onload but has the onload in the code: http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/rLqvvj48/

Comment: ok thanks mplungjan i will i think i almost have it thanks though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help you out a bit:

```
for(var i=99; i>0; i--){
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += i + "Bottles on the wall take one down, pass it around." + "<br>";
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/a0knrxzs/

EDIT:
We don't need a while loop, a for loop will just stop when it is no longer greater than 0. While loops are for stopping the loop after a something has been changed.

Comment: Thanks so much now i see how to do it that helps me so much thank you for the help everyone and why did i get a minus vote

Comment: Because it is very trivial and some people do not give a noob a chance

Comment: @Matthew - perhaps because you didn't state what your result was and what made you think there's a problem. (It was obvious, I think, but many don't like having to work out the problem and then provide tips on how to solve it)

Comment: yeah i know right and how would i out put for 0 bottles of beer on the wall

Comment: i thought people come on here for help and get tip and i am still woking on it to get the result thanks

Comment: @Matthew You should experiment with your variables.

Comment: @mplugian Sometimes seeing it makes things click. Examples are how some people learn, especially when you're JUST starting to out. I personally see no benefit in watching people struggle, when you could just tell him and give them a point in the right direction.

Comment: ok i will but if i stall have trouble i will let you know you are very helpful @dustindowell22

Comment: yes thats why i put my question on here it was just for some one to show or tell me where i was going wrong and thanks to dustindowell22 it really helped me i will be able to make my song work thanks to him

Comment: @mplungjan It's a place for beginners, is it really that bad?

Comment: @mplungjan Feel free to make a better suggestion since I am apparently inadequate. I was just helping out a beginner.

Comment: w3schools is a very poor resource since it has many errors and bad habits. MDN and quirksmode are much better.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's a bad place for beginners. I have yet to come across any misinformation on it personally. It's all just hype anymore. It might have sucked 5 years ago (I wouldn't know) but I've had no problems with it.